# How to insert default values in SQL table?

Tags: t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
create table1 (field1 int,
               field2 int default 5557,
               field3 int default 1337, 
               field4 int default 1337)
```

I want to insert a row which has the default values for field2 and field4.

I've tried `insert into table1 values (5,null,10,null)` but it doesn't work and `ISNULL(field2,default)` doesn't work either.

How can I tell the database to use the default value for the column when I insert a row?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900996) for the case where *all* columns have default values.

Comment: Please, never post "_doesn't work_" without defining **how**.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Just don't include the columns that you want to use the default value for in your insert statement.  For instance:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field3) VALUES (5, 10);
```

...will take the default values for `field2` and `field4`, and assign 5 to `field1` and 10 to `field3`.

Comment: What if column has not defined default values and is also set to "NOT ALLOW NULLS"?

Comment: @binki Maybe I should rephrase my comment: "aroth: your answer isn't complete, because of possible exception when the column has not defined default values and is also set to 'NOT ALLOW NULLS'"

Comment: @Danon - The OP states "I want to insert a row which has the default values for field2 and field4" and asks "How can I tell the database to use the default value for the column when I insert a row?".  You're correct that this answer doesn't cover the case when default values _aren't_ defined, however as the question is explicitly _not_ asking about that case it's not really accurate to describe the answer as incomplete.  You're talking about a completely different question (which is best asked as a separate question).

Comment: Why does SO bury this accepted answer with almost 100 upvotes at the 6th position?

Answer (score 198):

Best practice it to list your columns so you're independent of table changes (new column or column order etc)

```
insert into table1 (field1, field3)  values (5,10)
```

However, if you don't want to do this, use the `DEFAULT` keyword

```
insert into table1 values (5, DEFAULT, 10, DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. Note: you can also specify the columns and values, passing DEFAULT instead of NULL and you'll get the default value if there is a DEFAULT constraint, or NULL if the column is nullable and no default constraint is specified.

Comment: This _does_ work, but when I tried to be fancy using `(CASE WHEN This = That THEN 'SpecifiedValue' ELSE DEFAULT END)` it would _not_ work, much to my chagrin.  I still had to either prepare multiple Insert-Statements to cover all my scenarios or use Dynamic-SQL.  :(

Comment: For some reason I couldn't make this work with the DB Browser for SQLite. Kept complaining about a syntax error around `DEFAULT`. I had to specify the non-default columns as in the top example, then just provide values for those, and then it finally worked.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) says nothing about that. Is this use of `DEFAULT` safe? (If it's undocumented, we cannot complain when the functionality is omitted in the future version of sqlite3 without any notice.)

Comment: @ynn In addition, the book [*Using SQLite*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521196.do) (p.326) says "*There is no way to specify a default value except by leaving the column out of the column list, or knowing what the default value is and explicitly inserting it.*".

Answer (score 65):

This works if all the columns have associated defaults and one does not want to specify the column names:

```
insert into your_table
default values
```

Answer (score 8):

Try it like this

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field3) VALUES (5,10)
```

Then field2 and field4 should have default values.

Answer (score 8):

I had a case where I had a very simple table, and I basically just wanted an extra row with just the default values. Not sure if there is a prettier way of doing it, but here's one way:

This sets every column in the new row to its default value:

```
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES ()
```

*Note: This is extra useful for MySQL where* `INSERT INTO your_table DEFAULT VALUES` *does not work.*

Comment: I can confirm that this is the solution for MySQL , whereas "default" works for SQLite

Answer (score 3):

If your columns should not contain `NULL` values, you need to define the columns as `NOT NULL` as well, otherwise the passed in `NULL` will be used instead of the default and not produce an error.

If you don't pass in *any* value to these fields (which requires you to specify the fields that you *do* want to use), the defaults will be used:

```
INSERT INTO 
  table1 (field1, field3) 
VALUES   (5,10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write in this way

```
GO
ALTER TABLE Table_name  ADD
column_name decimal(18, 2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Constant_name DEFAULT 0
GO
ALTER TABLE Table_name SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert the default values you should omit them something like this :

```
Insert into Table (Field2) values(5)
```

All other fields will have null or their default values if it has defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #dum (id int identity(1,1) primary key, def int NOT NULL default(5), name varchar(25))

-- this works
INSERT #dum (def, name) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'jeff')

SELECT * FROM #dum;

DECLARE @some int 

-- this *doesn't* work and I think it should
INSERT #dum (def, name)
VALUES (ISNULL(@some, DEFAULT), 'george')

SELECT * FROM #dum;
```

Answer (score -7):

```
CREATE PROC SP_EMPLOYEE                             --By Using TYPE parameter and CASE  in Stored procedure
(@TYPE INT)
AS
BEGIN
IF @TYPE=1
BEGIN
SELECT DESIGID,DESIGNAME FROM GP_DESIGNATION
END
IF @TYPE=2
BEGIN
SELECT ID,NAME,DESIGNAME,
case D.ISACTIVE when 'Y' then 'ISACTIVE' when 'N' then 'INACTIVE' else 'not' end as ACTIVE
 FROM GP_EMPLOYEEDETAILS ED 
  JOIN  GP_DESIGNATION D ON ED.DESIGNATION=D.DESIGID
END
END
```

Comment: I don't think this an answer.