# Inserting default values if column value is 'None' using slick

Tags: sql, scala, null, slick

My problem is simple.

I have a column `seqNum: Double` which is `NOT NULL DEFAULT 1` in `CREATE TABLE` statement as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table
(
    ...
    seq_num DECIMAL(18,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    ...
);
```

User can enter a value for `seqNum` or not from UI. So the accepting `PLAY` form is like:

```
case class SomeCaseClass(..., seqNum: Option[Double], ...)
val secForm = Form(mapping(
    ...
    "seqNum" -> optional(of[Double]),
    ...
  )(SomeCaseClass.apply)(SomeCaseClass.unapply))
```

The slick Table Schema & Objects looks like this:

```
case class SomeSection (
   ...
   seqNum: Option[Double],
   ...
)
class SomeSections(tag: Tag) extends Table[SomeSection](tag, "some_table") {
  def * = (
      ...
      seqNum.?,
      ...
    ) <> (SomeSection.tupled, SomeSection.unapply _)

  ...
  def seqNum = column[Double]("seq_num", O.NotNull, O.Default(1))
  ...
}
object SomeSections {

  val someSections = TableQuery[SomeSections]
  val autoInc = someSections returning someSections.map(_.sectionId)

  def insert(s: someSection)(implicit session: Session) = {
     autoInc.insert(s)
  }
}
```

When I'm sending `seqNum` from UI, everything is works fine but when `None` is there, it breaks saying that **cannot insert NULL in NOT NULL column** which is correct. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777362/how-to-insert-default-values-in-sql-table) explains why.

But how to solve this problem using `slick`? Can't understand where should I check about `None`? I'm creating & sending an object of `SomeSection` to `insert` method of `SomeSections` Object.

I'm using sql-server, if it matters.

Answer (score 8):

Using the default requires not inserting the value at all rather than inserting NULL. This means you will need a custom projection to insert to.

`people.map(_.name).insert("Chris")` will use defaults for all other fields. The limitations of scala's native tuple transformations and case class transformations can make this a bit of a hassle. Things like Slick's HLists, Shapeless, Scala Records or Scala XR can help, but are not trivial or very experimental at the moment.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for mapped columns; `Slick does not know how to map the given types`. Not sure why, though.

Answer (score -1):

Either you enforce the `Option` passed to Slick by suffixing it with a `.getOrElse(theDefault)`, or you make the DB accepts `NULL` (from a `None` value) and defaults it using some trigger.

Comment: If I'll use `.getOrElse(theDefault)` then the default value set while creating table will be of no use, as I'll be passing something.

Comment: Passing `None` is not passing nothing.