# How do I insert field having default value in Slick

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

Given mapping having `NOT NULL` field `str` with a default value:

```
case class Tst(id: Option[Int] = None, ii: Int, str: String)
class Tsts(tag: Tag) extends Table[Tst](tag, "tsts") {
  def id = column[Option[Int]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def ii = column[Int]("ii")
  def str = column[String]("str", O.Default("ddd"))
  def * = (id, ii, str) <> (Tst.tupled, Tst.unapply)
}
```

How do I insert object specifying the field value if I have it:

```
Tst(ii = 1, str = "aaa")
```

and skipping it if I don't:

```
Tst(ii = 1)
```

Yes, I know the last statement will not compile.
I tried using `Option[String]` and other things. It ends up with either inserting `null` or failing with `can't be null` error

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471399/inserting-default-values-if-column-value-is-none-using-slick/ (more or less).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler depends on you putting default values at the end, like:

```
scala> case class TST(ii: Int, str: String = "aaa", id: Option[Int] = None)
defined class TST

scala> new TST(3)
res0: TST = TST(3,aaa,None)
```

Edit: Just realized I didn't answer completely:

```
scala> new TST(3, id = Some(1))
res1: TST = TST(3,aaa,Some(1))

scala> new TST(3, str = "bbb")
res2: TST = TST(3,bbb,None)
```

Comment: This approach doesn't use the default value provided by the DB. The default could be changed in the future, be current date or calculated some other way

Comment: Oh, I see you changed the question now...

I think the only option then is to create an update statement that does not include the values on the case class, or have it conditionally include those values if they are defined.

Comment: Edit: *(values on the case class) should be *(values you want defaulted)