# How to omit column values when doing a bulk-insert slick 3.x?

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I have a JOURNAL table where the INSERT_DATE column should be filled by the DB with the current date and time when the record is inserted. I did not use the TIMESTAMP type on purpose, because of its limited range.

```
class Journal(tag: Tag) extends Table[JournalEntry](tag, "JOURNAL") { 
   def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
   def insertDate = column[OffsetDateTime]("INSERT_DATE", SqlType("DateTime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))(localDateTimeColumnType)
   def valueDate = column[OffsetDateTime]("VALUE_DATE", SqlType("DateTime"))(localDateTimeColumnType)
   def amount = column[Int]("AMOUNT")
   def note = column[String]("NOTE", O.Length(100))

   def * : ProvenShape[JournalEntry] = (id.?, insertDate.?, valueDate, amount, note) 
     <> ((JournalEntry.apply _).tupled, JournalEntry.unapply)
}
```

I also implement a case class:

```
case class JournalEntry(id: Option[Int], insertDate: Option[LocalDateTime], 
  valueDate: LocalDateTime, amount: Int, note: String)
```

When my app starts up, I populate the DB with random test data:

```
TableQuery[Journal] ++= Seq.fill(1000)(JournalEntry(None, Some(LocalDateTime.now()), 
   LocalDateTime.of(2006 + Random.nextInt(10), 1 + Random.nextInt(11), 
   1 + Random.nextInt(27),Random.nextInt(24), Random.nextInt(60)), Random.nextInt(),
   TestDatabase.randomString(100)))
```

This works, but the INSERT_DATE ist set by the JVM not by the Database. The Slick docs say that columns should be omitted, if one wants the default value to get inserted. But I just dont get how I omit columns if I have a case class.

I also found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471399/inserting-default-values-if-column-value-is-none-using-slick) but could not figure out how to use it in my context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The Slick docs give an example of such omission right in the first code snippet [here](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html#inserting). Follow the steps or [the cvogt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28482131/5343328) and you will arrive at the solution:

`TableQuery[Journal].map(je => (je.id, je.valueDate, je.amount, je.note)) ++= Seq.fill(1000)((None, LocalDateTime.of(2006 + Random.nextInt(10), 1 + Random.nextInt(11), 1 + Random.nextInt(27),Random.nextInt(24), Random.nextInt(60)), Random.nextInt(), TestDatabase.randomString(100)))`

Comment: Does not work for me: `[error] Slick does not know how to map the given types.
[error] Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
[error]   Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
[error]      Source type: (slick.lifted.Rep[Int], slick.lifted.Rep[java.time.LocalDateTime], slick.lifted.Rep[Int], slick.lifted.Rep[String])
[error]    Unpacked type: T
[error]      Packed type: G
[error]         TableQuery[Journal].map(je => (je.id, je.valueDate, je.amount, je.note)) ++=`

Answer (score 1):

I work in the following way:

```
import java.time.{ ZonedDateTime, ZoneOffset}
import slick.profile.SqlProfile.ColumnOption.SqlType
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.Await

implicit val zonedDateTimeType = MappedColumnType.base[ZonedDateTime, Timestamp](
    {dt =>Timestamp.from(dt.toInstant)},
    {ts =>ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(ts.toInstant, ZoneOffset.UTC)}
)

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, ZonedDateTime)](tag, "users") {
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def createAt = column[ZonedDateTime]("create_at", SqlType("timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    def * = (name, createAt)
}

val users = TableQuery[Users]
val setup = DBIO.seq(
    users.schema.create,
    users.map(u => (u.name)) ++= Seq(("Amy"), ("Bob"), ("Chris"), ("Dave"))
Await.result(db.run(setup), Duration.Inf)
```

I am not using case class here, just a tuple.