# SQL Server insert empty instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2014

Given a table 'test' with the following fields:

- **id**: int. Primary key. Autoincrement by 1.
- **creation_date**: datetime. GETDATE() by default value.

My intention is to insert an empty statement, just to register the event of the insertion. I thought that as the *id* is an autoincrement and the *creation_date* has a value by default, a record could be inserted without specifying any value. I know that this can be done by adding a third field and specifying the value in the insertion, but my question is:

Can something like a plain `INSERT INTO test` be done?

Thanks

Comment: `insert into test values (default, default)`

Comment: or [How to insert default values in SQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777362/how-to-insert-default-values-in-sql-table)

Comment: thanks for the fast replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO test DEFAULT VALUES
```

Comment: thank you for the fast reply