# Insert part of one table into another with original default attribute value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with the following schema,

- table1 (a int, b int, c int, d int default 123)
- table2 (a int, b int, c int, e int)

I would like to update the `(a,b,c)` columns of `table2` into `table1`, but keep the default value of `d`.

For example, with the following record

```
------------------------
table1 | a | b | c | d |
------------------------
       | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
------------------------
```

and

```
------------------------
table2 | a | b | c | e |
------------------------
       | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
------------------------
```

I would like an output of:

```
--------------------------
table1 | a | b | c | d   |
--------------------------
       | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4   |
       | 5 | 6 | 7 | 123 |
--------------------------
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO table1(a, b, c, d) 
VALUES ((SELECT a, b, c FROM table2), DEFAULT)
```

This query has an invalid syntax, because it returns the table in the sub-query and uses it as a value.

I have also tried to avoid this solution below, because it hides the fact, that the default value of `d` is used. I really want to explicitly make it default to make it clear.

```
INSERT INTO table1(a, b, c) 
    SELECT a, b, c  
    FROM table2
```

Is there a way to combine

```
INSERT .. VALUES(..)
```

with

```
INSERT.. SELECT.. FROM table
```

or just another way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: What's wrong with `INSERT INTO table1(a, b, c) SELECT a, b, c FROM table2`?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777362/how-to-insert-default-values-in-sql-table) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code hunts down the default value definition for a specific column in a specific table and cobbles it into an integer. The value can then be used to explicitly supply the default value in other statements, e.g. `insert`.

```
-- if object_id( N'Samples', N'U' ) is not NULL
--   drop table Samples;

create table Samples ( Id Int Identity, Foo Int Default 42, Bar Int );

-- Get the default value from the metadata.
declare @FooDefaultValue as NVarChar(32); -- Note:   sys.default_constraints.definition   is declared as   NVarChar(max) .
select @FooDefaultValue = sdf.definition
  from sys.tables as st inner join
    sys.columns as sc on sc.object_id = st.object_id inner join
    sys.default_constraints as sdf on sdf.object_id = sc.default_object_id
    where st.name = 'Samples' and sc.name = 'Foo';
select @FooDefaultValue as 'Default Value NVarChar';

-- Cobble it from a string to an integer (since we know the correct data type).
declare @FooDefaultValueInteger as Int =
  Cast( Replace( Replace( @FooDefaultValue, '(', '' ), ')', '' ) as Int );
select @FooDefaultValueInteger as 'Default Value Integer';

-- Insert a few rows with data for both columns.
insert into Samples ( Foo, Bar )
  select Foo, Bar
    from ( values ( 1, 1 ), ( 2, 2 ), ( 3, 3 ) ) as Arthur( Foo, Bar );

-- Insert a few rows with an explicit default value for   Foo .
insert into Samples ( Foo, Bar )
  select @FooDefaultValueInteger, Bar
    from ( values ( 5 ), ( 6 ), ( 7 ) ) as Dent( Bar );

-- Display the results.
select * from Samples;

drop table Samples;
```

This is clumsy at best. The cobbling from string to integer strikes me as fragile. It should probably have more validation of the schema name, ... . It gets more interesting when the table is temporary. And unravels completely if the table is a variable. By separating getting the default value from its use it opens the possibility of names failing to agree, i.e. a quick cut'n'paste without editing the table or column name could result in *bad things*.

All said, I'd avoid this and add a comment near or in the `insert` explaining what ought to occur.

Comment: Thanks. If this is the easiest way, then I think you have fully answered my question. I will also stick with a comment solution as you mentioned, because my intent was to simplify (to not hide the relevant info). I'm pretty new to sql, still trying to learn do-s and don't-s of the syntax. That's why the question may sound little odd for you.

Comment: You can always go to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com) and suggest a new SQL Server function `ColumnDefault( <column name> )` returning a [`sql_variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql) matching the column's data type would be useful. Holding your breath would not be advisable.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table1 values (a, b, c) 
    SELECT a, b, c FROM table2
```

Comment: Thanks. This is correct of course. But I am looking for a solution, where `default` keyword was used for an attribute `d`.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged.