# Insert with 2 DEFAULT constraints in a row

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a create table script like that:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    age INT DEFAULT 18,
    iq INT DEFAULT 100
);
```

So I have two DEFAULT constraints in a row. Now I make an insertion like that:

```
INSERT INTO Person VALUES(1,85);
```

How do we know if we skip the attribute `age` or the attribute `iq`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should edit your question and specify which type of SQL in the tags.

Comment: It was intentional, I wanted to be broad.

Comment: Voting to close as Too Broad.  There are way too many types of RDMS that an answer would need to cover in order to be considered complete.

Comment: But it seems that rollstuhlfahrer's answer managed perfectly to do that. We don't have to get into the most obscure RDMS, only the main ones.

Comment: That's a default _value_, not a "constraint" - and the INSERT statement is actually invalid standard SQL.

Comment: W3school called it a constraint [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp). What do you mean invalid standard SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question: it depends. ;-)

## MySQL

Running your query on MySQL will get you the following error:

```
Error: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

For MySQL you need to tell the DBMS which columns you want to have (and which columns the DB should fill with default data). Like this:

```
INSERT INTO Person(id, age) VALUES(1,85);
```

Or you need to tell the DB, where to use default values. You can pass the keyword `DEFAULT` for these columns:

```
INSERT INTO Person VALUES(1,85, DEFAULT);
```

See: [MySQL INSERT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

## SQLite

SQLite acts like MySQL, the error message here is:

```
SQLITE_ERROR: table Person has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied
```

Which means, you have to specify the columns.

## PostgreSQL

Running the query on a PostgreSQL table will yield

```
id  age iq
1   85  100
```

Here PostgreSQL will use the columns from the table definition in the defined order and fill all remaining columns with the default value.

## MS SQL Server

See: [How to insert default values in SQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777362/how-to-insert-default-values-in-sql-table)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. More specifically for MySQL, isn't there a quicker method than rewriting all the columns, like for instance a DEFAULT clause that we would put in the INSERT?

Comment: Yes, there is. Edited my answer.