# bulk insert with default constraint

Tags: constraints, primary-key, rdbms, default-constraint

I have two table tblPerson and tblGender

the coulmn 'GenderID'in tblPerson is a foriegn key for the coulmn 'ID'(primary) in the tblGender

here is a default contarint

```
Alter Table tblPerson
    Add constraint DF_tblPerson_GenderID
    Default 4 for GENDERID
```

now the insert query is

```
insert into tblPerson (ID,[Name],EmailID,GenderID)values
    (4,'Riya','riya@.com',2),
    (5,'Raj','raj@.com',3),
    (6,'Tisha','tisha@.com',2),
    (7,'Stephen','stephen@.com'); // here im getting the error
```

now as you can see in the 7 I'm trying to add nothing in the genderid column and i thought it will be considered as a default constraint

but it is giving me error 'The number of columns for each row in a table value constructor must be the same.'

Comment: Please edit the tags and tell us what kind of RDBS. SQL Server? Oracle? SQLLite? They probably all do this differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a T-SQL (SQL Server) specific answer. You should tag your question with the actual RDBMS. Your code looks like T-SQL with the `[` and `]` but who knows....

Since you can't change the column list, you need to use the `default` keyword to trigger a default.

```
INSERT INTO tblPerson (ID, [Name], EmailID, GenderID) VALUES
    (4, 'Riya', 'riya@.com', 2),
    (5, 'Raj', 'raj@.com', 3),
    (6, 'Tisha', 'tisha@.com', 2),
    (7, 'Stephen', 'Stephen@.com',default)
```

See here for an example. This is a T-SQL answer for a SQLLite question.

[How to insert default values in SQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777362/how-to-insert-default-values-in-sql-table)

I can't find a clear example of this in the T-SQL docs. This has a very vague description

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16